# Post compile hook latexmk

Tags: latexmk, hooks, bash

Is there something like a "post compile hook" for latexmk.

I want to configure latexmk to run some scripts automatically after a compilation process is completed.

Answer (score 6):

Yes.  Look at the latexmk documentation for the configuration variables `$compiling_cmd`, `$success_cmd` and `$failure_cmd`.

*N.B.* In response to a comment: The above only work in preview-continuous mode.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried to add the example from the manual fur `$success_cmd` but it didn't work. Then I just tried the more simple variant `$success_cmd = "okular";` just to start `okular` for testing purposes after successful compilation, however this also doesn't work. By the way, it says that the pdflatex rule is out of date...

Comment: Sorry.  I forgot those only work in preview-continuous mode.  I'll amend my answer. Could you describe in more detail what you want to do.  Depending on exactly  what your needs are, there may be a way of doing what you want without modifying latexmk.

Comment: I have a graphics directory set via texinputs After compiling I want to run a script which creates (or deletes) hardlinks of the pictures used into subdirectory of my project.

Comment: I ended up using Hook::WrapSub on `rdb_make`.