# How to run a command before compiling (hook script) in latexmk?

Tags: latexmk, hooks, bash

I use latexmk to compile a project.
It should run some bash commands before starting to compile.

I tried to add

```perl
$compiling_cmd="date >> /tmp/compiled.log";
```

to the local `.latexmkrc` file. But it is only evaluated, if I run latexmk with
`latexmk -pvc` but not with `latexmk`.

There is a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299822/post-compile-hook-latexmk/299867) about a post compile hook.

Comment: As you've found, this method only works in preview-continuous mode (as is  documented). This is simply because the uses which I designed it for seemed useful only in preview-continuous mode.  To have something that works without that restriction would need a modification of `latexmk`.  It seems it would be a useful extension, I agree.

Answer (score 5):

You can add

```perl
system("date >> /tmp/compiled.log");
```

to your `latexmk.rc`. The limitation is, that it is executed with every run of `latexmk` (even when cleaning) and only once per invocation; not with each compilation run. (Your question was not 100% clear on whether this is sufficient). I use this approach to run `make` from `latexmk`, as `latexmk` is integrated into my IDE.